# How to compute compound interest of historical stock price

Tags: c#, math

I am doing a study of the  S&P since it's inception.

The initial open price on Dec 30, 1927 was 17.66.

93 years later, on Dec 12, the price closed at 3663.46.  (33950 days)

The total Percentage return is 2,064,439.39% increase (TotalPercentage = (Gain / Cost) * 100)

How would I calculate that on a compounding basis?  In other words, I want to be able to say "The average Compounded Yearly Rate of return is  xx%.  I think that would be much more meaningful.

More specifically, how do I calculate that in c#?

I am a programmer, not a math major, so I apologize if my math concepts are naïve.

Comment: Your first step would be to look up how to calculate what you are looking for. Hint: try "internal rate of return". Then you need to decide if you are calculating it based on compounding on a day basis, a month basis, or a yearly basis. You could also calculate it on a *continuous* basis (in which case, it's just an exponential). Consider trying to get it working on Excel first (without using the built-in function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment has said, you should be looking for what you *actually* wanted to calculate.

If you wanted only a simple compound yearly return, you can just look for the n-th root. That is,

[image: formula]

[image: formula]

In C#, that would be

```
Math.Pow(3663.46 / 17.66, 1.0 / 93)
```

That would yield around 5.9% P.A. Underwhelming. But we haven't account for other factors, like the dividends distributed. And if we talk about the dividend we might also wanted to look for the dividend reinvested return. That would require more information, like the daily closing price and the dividend record of the index trust fund. Then we will be wondering should we consider the time-weight, or money-weight return. But that would be beyond the scope of this *programming question*.

Comment: Thank You @JackySky, I have the Yield working correctly as per the above. Now, for the Dividends, I have the daily closing price for the period in question in a database, as well as the Yearly dividend information. What would I include that in the yield calculation assuming all dividends were re-invested?

Comment: @GregGum, I'm afraid that will be a much more complicated problem. One does not simply "buy' an index - we could buy an index fund that track the performance of the index, but the earliest index fund does not exist until 1975. If you really want to calculate the return of investing into SPX since 1927, you probably have to simulate buying the index component stocks, and reinvesting the dividends quarter by quarter. The index components also changes from time to time, so you have to account for that as well. Probably there isn't a trivial solution to your question.

Comment: It's just a study, so it doesn't have to be perfect - ie, i am going to assume that one could buy the index from the start.  I only have yearly dividend information to work from, so i am going to try using that to re-invest yearly and see what the outcome is.  This is mainly for a learning experience for me. I know it's not trivial, but the programming aspect is easy for me (professional c# guy) but the math concepts are a bit hazy, so this helps me learn. I appreciate your input

Comment: In case anyone wants to know, I completed this study and between 1927 and 2020, the compounded return I came up with on the S&P including reinvesting the dividends is 9.9%.  It is interesting to note that this is pretty much the same as is usually mentioned in articles on the market overall return.

Comment: That's an interesting find. Googling Berkshire annual return since inception (1965) give 20.5%, and that didn't even beat S&P of the same period. I assume the early years really dragged its performance?

Comment: @JackSky, that is a great question and I am going to work on it further using different time periods to see the effect.  For example, take a 20 year period starting from 1927 and calculate the results, then 1928, and so on until 2000-2020.  This will show the effect of when a person gets into, and then out of the market at all possible 20 year periods.  The idea is to come up with the "probability" of making a profit using a 20 year hold period. I use 20 years as that seems to me the longest anyone could actually reasonably hold a stock on practical terms.